# Getting bash script to enter in numbers in an 'interactive mode' prompt

Tags: linux, bash

There is an interactive mode that can be turned on in the program ORCA I am using by typing in the following command:

```
module load  openmpi/2.1.2 orca/orca_4_0_1_2_linux_x86-64_openmpi202
```

Once this is enabled, I can give it a command to plot a graph with:

```
orca_plot IPC_CAS1_restart2f-NEVPT2.gbw -i
```

The program then offers me choices, which I can choose from by entering a number into the prompt. I wish to automate this process by having a bash script that enters a specific sequence of numbers for me (i.e. 1, then 3, then 2, then 7 for example).

My script looks like the following,

```
#!/bin/bash 
module load  openmpi/2.1.2 orca/orca_4_0_1_2_linux_x86-64_openmpi202
orca_plot IPC_CAS1_restart2f-NEVPT2.gbw -i
1
3
2 
7
```

I get the messages 
"line 4: 1: command not found", "line 5: 3: "command not found", "line 7: 2: command not found", "line 8: 7: command not found".

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert those lines in the script into input to orca_plot.  Use a heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash 
module load  openmpi/2.1.2 orca/orca_4_0_1_2_linux_x86-64_openmpi202
orca_plot IPC_CAS1_restart2f-NEVPT2.gbw -i << EOF
1
3
2 
7 
EOF
```